# Django Import Error: No module named apps

Tags: python, django, module, directory, importerror

I just checked out a project with git. The project structure is

```
project
  apps
    myapp
      settings
        __init__.py
      __init__.py
    manage.py
```

There are other directories and files, but I think those are the important ones.

When I run the server  I get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Dev/project/apps/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'apps.myapp.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named apps.myapp.settings
```

When running `manage.py check` I get `ImportError: No module named apps.` so I guess the problem has nothing to do with my setting module but with my apps directory. 
I'm not sure why it can't find my module apps, because project is on my `sys.path` and the direcory `apps` obviously exists. As I'm not very experienced as a Python developer I don't find a solution myself.

Comment: Can you paste the complete stack trace of the error you get?

Comment: I just edited my question because it didn't tell the complete problem.

Comment: I was having an almost similar problem, but my error was `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.Apps'` so when I searched that using Google, it led me to this question. My problem was because I used capital A for "Apps". Spent a good 30 minutes so yeah, check your spelling if this happened to you too.

Answer (score 25):

You need to add an empty `__init__.py` (4 underscores in total) file in the `apps` folder for it to be recognized by Python as a package.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more informations.

Comment: And just a note to the OP: Use **two** sets of **two** underscores. The question posted only has singles, while this answer has the correct number.

Comment: This works, but every project this project is depending on has the same structure and I can't change those projects. As those projects are running at the production server there must be something else I can do without creating a file.

Comment: No, there isn't. `__init__.py`  files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Answer (score 14):

This can also happen if you installed your app in `settings.py` in your main project folder, before running this:

```
python manage.py startapp [app-name]
```

Comment it out, create the app (should work now), then put the line back into the `settings.py` file and continue on.

Comment: You were correct, if the app name is already added to the settings.py the `python manage.py startapp` would throw Module not found error

Answer (score 11):

Note that in Django 1.9 there is a module called django.apps

Avoiding name clashes with built-in modules is generally advised

Answer (score 11):

If you've used the `django-admin startapp myapp` command, it creates this file: `myapp/apps.py`.

It could be conflicting with your `apps/` module folder. A hidden `apps.pyc` file could be in your `myapp/` folder.

Try removing these:

- `project/apps/myapp/apps.py`
- `project/apps/myapp/apps.pyc`

Comment: what if i want to use an `apps` subdirectory and keep the `myapp/apps.py` file also? is there no way to explicitly indicate where you want to import from with `from apps.myapp import ...` ?

django recommends using `apps.py` in an app directory for subclassing `AppConfig` but this conflicts with an `apps` directory very easily. i guess i'll just use `config.py` instead of `apps.py`

Answer (score 6):

It might be a comma missing after your config path:

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'palc.apps.PalcConfig', # This comma
    'django.contrib.admin',
     ...]
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that in `Django 1.9`, you can add your app into the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

If your app name is `app` and you have created models in it, then go to the `settings.py` file and add your app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'app'
]
```

Answer (score 2):

First, check your `manage.py` and make sure it has the correct reference to `myapp`.

**...apps/myapp/manage.py**

```
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
...
```

If the settings are correct, check the Python interpreter. If you're using virtualenv, errors can occur when you use the global Python instead of the virtual environment. The use of global Python can be caused by improperly setting up your IDE, user error or incorrect bin/bash in `manage.py`.

To make sure `manage.py` is running on the virtual env, check the first line in `manage.py`. By default the file reads:

```
#!/usr/bin python
```

Change that to:

```
#!/path/to/virtualenv/bin python
```

Now, check the Terminal and what Python version it's using. Then, activate the virtualenv:

```
[user@pc] #: source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate 
(venv) [user@pc] #: pip list
```

Confirm Django is installed. If it is and it's still not working correctly, then upgrade it with `pip`:

```
(venv) [user@pc] #: pip install --upgrade django
```

If none of the above works even though the Python version is correct, you're using the right Python environment and `manage.py` is set up correctly, then that means the error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For people who are here becuase adding a new view and bumped into this problem I did the above desceribed by aumo For me worked adding a empty **init.py** inside my folder view and inside the folder I was adding eg.

```
-- example-folder

  --   views
  -- `__init.py__`
  -- `index.py`

-- `__init.py__`
-- `urls.py`
```

hope makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Command: `python manage.py startapp app_name`

Class name must be the same as `app_name` in `models.py` file and then add your `app_name` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this command to start an app:

```
django-admin startapp appexample
```

...then, the `AppexampleConfig` class should not be listed in the `settings.py` file.

Just add the app name (e.g. `appexample`) in `INSTALLED_APPS` list. Avoid using: `appexample.app.AppexampleConfig`.

Usually, the `AppexampleConfig` class is a subclass of the `django.apps.Appconfig` class that represents a Django application and its configuration. It just defines the name class attribute and sets its value to `Appexample`.

Answer (score 0):

I got past this issue after running `python3 manage.py runserver` instead of `python manage.py runserver`
 Wasted a solid 25 minutes on that one...

Answer (score 0):

Please make that your app is in the root directory of your project. By this I mean if by mistake you start an app outside your main directory, Django will not be able to find your app and the only solution is to move it to your project's main directory. The screenshots show how to fix the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OWqM.png)
the first images show the wish also prompts this error that your apps are not loaded yet when you run the app.

The second screenshot shows how to fix the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNEJk.png)
This is what I mean that the app should be in the same directory of the main project. In my case my main directory is crmapp.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue.
In settings.py I printed the SYS path by:

```
  import sys
  print(sys.path)
```

It turned out that main path to the project directory was not included, so I had to add it manually here.

```
  import sys
  sys.path.append(<path to my main project dir>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with Django 3.1.5.

Solved it by deleting all `__pycache__` folders in the project.

Answer (score 0):

another possible cause for this is if the Django app in question was created somewhere 'outside' the project root. E.g., executing:

> project_root/manage.py startapp search

, I didn't realize that my Django app was created in the current folder, not inside the project root (in my case, named just that, 'project_root', haha). Django conventions dictate that the app, referenced in this case by 'search' in **INSTALLED_APPS** inside *settings.py*, should be on the **BASE_DIR** (project_root in my case).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Docker for deploying your application with default command like:

`uwsgi --socket=0.0.0.0:9000 --module=myapp.wsgi:application --py-autoreload=1`

make sure to change your working directory in the end of Dockerfile like:

`WORKDIR /absolute/path/to/source/code`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the virtual enviroment and upgrade your django using command `pip install --upgrade Django`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you first execute `python manage.py startapp app_name` and then add app_name into `settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

When executing **(in TERMINAL)**

```
python manage.py startapp (your_app_name)
```

First check apps.py in (your_app_name) folder.

It should be something like this:

```
class (__auto_generated__)Config(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = '(your_app_name')
```

Second check settings.py, in `INSTALLED_APPS['']`, you must have 'your_app_name'

**Be careful when you change your app names**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))` to `manage.py` file:

```py
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    # ⬇️⬇️⬇️ HERE ⬇️⬇️⬇️    
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Check [complete description of the issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77143207/11208548)

Answer (score -1):

On my side, I have forgotten the comma (',')

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'app',
]
```