# ImportError: No module named apps

Tags: python, django

I want to create a new project and for that I am using **django-admin startproject** command but it is giving me error **"No module named apps"**. I have checked that django is installed and confirmed using **django-admin --version**.

I stuck at this point for very long time, may be silly mistake but I don't have any idea what I am missing. There is full stack trace in given below image. Any single hint would be really helpful.

PS: I am working on windows OS.

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001009/django-import-error-no-module-named-apps

Comment: Please don't include code as an image in your question. Edit your question and copy-paste the traceback, using a codeblock instead.

Comment: Can you verify that there is no `apps` subdirectory in the directory `d:\production\saleor\jewel\venv\lib\site-packages\django\`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your virtualenv packages with

`pip freeze`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `django-admin startproject foo` without writing the full path to django-admin.