# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ingredients'

Tags: graphene-python, graphene-django

Following the [Graphene-Django basic tutorial](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/#basic-tutorial) verbatim results in this helpful situation.

Maybe there is a dir problem or something? As soon as we add the installed app, it is not found?

Tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001009/django-import-error-no-module-named-apps)

Answer (score 1):

Try to open "cookbook/ingredients/" folder and change name in IngredientsConfig to `cookbook.ingredients`:

```
class IngredientsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'cookbook.ingredients'
```