# Django file structure: cannot import main module without export PYPATH

Tags: python, django, import, module, django-4.0

I am using Django 4.0.4

Here is my project structure:

```
root/
|   README.md
|-- app/
|   |-- init__.py
|   |-- manage.py
|   |-- project/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- settings.py
|   |   |-- urls.py
|   |   |-- etc...
|   |-- webapp/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- apps.py
|   |   |-- views.py
|   |   |-- utils/
|   |   |-- migrations/
|   |   |-- etc...
|   |-- mediafiles/
|-- docs/
```

The imports inside de files are structured like this:

- `apps.py` => `from app.project.settings import APP_NAME`
- `settings.py` => `from app.webapp.utils.paths import BASE_DIR`
- `urls.py` => `from app.webapp.views import home`
- `views.py` => `from app.webapp.models import MyModel`

In `settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "webapp",
    ...
]
```

In short, nothing very unusual, except that my root folder is one level higher than in a standard Django installation. However, as soon as I run

```bash
python app/manage.py runserver localhost:8000
# OR
python manage.py runserver localhost:8000 # (inside the `app/` directory)
```

I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

The problem is fixed if I set the `PYTHONPATH` variable inside the `root/` directory:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)"
```

If I remove the `app` from my imports, then the command works but my IDE (PyCharm) no longer lets me take advantage of import autocompletion...

> #### Why does this error happen?
>
> #### Is there a way to keep the import as so without needing to export the `PYTHONPATH`?

Thank you so much for your help!!

**Edit**: Apparently [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001009/django-import-error-no-module-named-apps) cover the same issue but without a response that fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

I have added a line to `manage.py` file and its works!

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))) # this line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```